# get correct position in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react js and react-contenteditable package to create a comment box with an ability to choose emojies.
I researched a lot, also in stackoverflow to find a way to get the correct position of user cursor and found some methodes that use window.getSelection() & getRangeAt(0). but the main problem is when getRangeAt reaches to new node it will reset and count again from 0 or 1 and I don't want this. I need to find correct cursor position and put new emojis into correct position something like all messengers.

My emoji picker create img node append that into old text.

This is comment my comment box & all child nodes in it:
[image]
[image]

Part of my code in keyUp event:

```
function getCaretPosition(element: HTMLElement | null) {
    if (element) {
      const w3 = typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined' && true;

      let caretPos = 0;

      if (w3) {
        let range;

        const w = window.getSelection();

        if (w) {
          range = w.getRangeAt(0);

          if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == element) {
            caretPos = range.endOffset;
          }
        }
      }

      console.log(caretPos);
    }
  }
```

I've tried to show the problem with a gif:

[image]